# Why does the setTheme() function not work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an android app and would like to implement a dark mode. Therefore, I have created a settings activity in which you can turn the dark mode on and off with the help of a toggle switch. The logic behind the switch works perfectly because I first implemented the whole thing with the help of a toggle switch. The logic behind the switch works perfectly, so I tested the whole thing with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` first. However, MODE_NIGHT_YES does not look good and therefore I decided to create a theme. To change the theme, I used `setTheme` as follows:

```
        darkSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppRoomDatabase database = AppRoomDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                SettingRoomDao settingRoomDao = database.getSettingRoomDao();
                if (darkSwitch.isChecked()) {

                    setTheme(R.style.Theme_StickyNötesDark);
                    settingRoomDao.updateStatus("darkMode", true);
                } else {
                    setTheme(R.style.Theme_StickyNötes);
                    settingRoomDao.updateStatus("darkMode", false);
                }
            }
        });
```

However, `setTheme` does not work. I found out with the help of the debugger that the theme always remains the same and the id does not change. What is the problem?

Comment: It does work, however it only works for *future* resource lookups and so your Views which are already initialised won't automagically change.

Comment: @RobCo Thanks for your comment. I don't quite understand what exactly I am supposed to tone now.  What exactly could I do because I don't have much experience with android apps yet?

Answer (score 2):

Call SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main) after setTheme().

Comment: You understood wrong @eXor420. You need to pass the id of the layout in that `setContentView()` not that style